# Splits by comma, but keep strings in double-quotes atomic

Tags: csv, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to figure out a regex pattern that splits the following string:

> 2022-09-22T03:55:59.433Z,,,,sm100,"sm100.w.gm.net=25 2.7.2 mailto:012323@eu-w1.as.com [IId=200023, Hostname=mky.wgm.net] Queued info",,SMTP,HAREDIRECT

into the following values:

```
2022-09-22T03:55:59.433Z,
,
,
,
sm100,
"sm100.w.gm.net=25 2.7.2 <mailto:012323@eu-w1.as.com> \[IId=200023, Hostname=mky.wgm.net\] Queued info",
,
SMTP,
HAREDIRECT
```

I **do not want** the regex expression to split the values in row #6 (the longest row) by comma, because even if there is a comma after **IId=200023**, the entire string should be considered atomic because it is enclosed with double quotes.

I have tried a lot of patterns inside [regex101](https://regex101.com/), and this pattern is as far as I've gotten:

```
,(?![" ])
```

[image]

It seems to have identified the commas correctly, but I can't find a way to change my regex pattern to find these groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[parse_csv()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsecsvfunction)

```
print txt = '2022-09-22T03:55:59.433Z,,,,sm100,"sm100.w.gm.net=25 2.7.2 mailto:012323@eu-w1.as.com [IId=200023, Hostname=mky.wgm.net] Queued info",,SMTP,HAREDIRECT'
| project parse_csv(txt)
```

| txt |
| --- |
| ["2022-09-22T03:55:59.4330000Z","","","","sm100","sm100.w.gm.net=25 2.7.2 mailto:012323@eu-w1.as.com [IId=200023, Hostname=mky.wgm.net] Queued info","","SMTP","HAREDIRECT"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAyWOTQuCQBQA70H/4dGlgvXxfJtEglBUkIegD09FhNgWVuuKu2ZBP76oucxtmLLKCwfu6SCCLhOzRyOPOSEZBkEYjHAg5U58sdonEp2fsMGLxkK5iANgHCKDTvO7MyH5LFmOVe01PqYWM6NhH8eniImIpYCFsa5ItYr07YXNv3KAda1qdYK8OJuOENtlshKLyWY%20izfzadJtt95QVuaqMgdlWll1zOyj933ufwDnOUvwvgAAAA==)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe it was so simple. When I tried splitting importing the text in Excel, it worked fine, but writing KQL in Log Analytics just split everything by comma (using just `split()`), whereas Excel somehow was able to interpret and keep things "atomic" and recognized distinct columns because they were enclosed in double quotes. Thanks a lot David!

Comment: Hello, sorry if this is not the right way to do it, but if you would have some time, could you please just have a look at my question about [Azure Data Explorer data ingestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75256793/20164299)? It would really be helpful to know if it is possible, what I am trying to do.