# Azure Data Explorer ingest text Log Files with custom delimiter

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, data-ingestion

I'm trying to use Azure Data Explorer to ingest some logs (IIS Logs, POP3 logs, IMAP logs) that contain values delimited by space.

I would have expected Azure Data Explorer to infer the correct schema from the files as separate columns, however it only identifies a single column with the entire data.

[image]

The reason for this seems to be the header and metadata rows, which I can't find a way to skip (would have thought there is a way to skip those).

However, even if I remove the metadata rows, manually, from the log file, it still doesn't seem to be able to recognize the schema for the table.

[image]

I have also tried to create the table before ingesting, using KQL queries, and instead of creating a new table, I ask the import to ingest into an already existing table. However, doing this, it doesn't identify any rows to be imported from the logs.

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly can be done, I thought Azure Data Explorer (and Log Explorer - tried that too, works the same) to be a perfect solution for log files created by Windows apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation might have been a good start point.
It is very clear as to what are the supported formats for ingestion.
IIS Logs, POP3 logs & IMAP logs are not listed.
[Data formats supported by Azure Data Explorer for ingestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats)

As to the TXT format, an entire line is ingested as a single value. No additional parsing there.

| Format | Extension | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TXT | .txt | A text file with lines delimited by \n. Empty lines are skipped. |

You could use the TXT format to load the data and then parse it and split it to columns, within ADX, probably by using REGEX.